# The distribution of $X_i-X_{(1)}$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

If $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from $Exp(1)$ and $X_{(1)}$ is the smallest exponential order statistic, how can I get the distribution of $X_i-X_{(1)}$?

Comment: $X_{(1)}$ is the smallest order statistics in this sample.

Comment: Yes. $X_{(1)}=min_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i.$

Comment: Are the $X_i$ independent ? Because if not, without more information, you can't find the distribution of $X_{(1)}$.

Comment: Assuming the $X_i$ are iid, note that $P(X_i-X_{(1)}=0)=\frac1n$, and that if $X_i > X_{(1)}$ then $X_i-X_{(1)} \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ due to the memorylessness property of the exponential distribution

Comment: Yes, $X_i$s are independent based on the definition of the random sample I learned.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2428277/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the $X_i$ are i.i.d.,

$$\begin{aligned}
P(X_i-X_{(1)} \leq t) &= P(X_i-t\leq X_{(1)})\\
&= P\left(\bigcap_k X_i-t\leq X_k\right)\\
&= E\left(1_{X_i-t\leq X_1} \ldots 1_{X_i-t\leq X_n}\right)\\
&= \int 1_{x_i-t\leq x_1} \ldots 1_{x_i-t\leq x_n} e^{-x_1}1_{x_1\geq 0}\ldots e^{-x_n}1_{x_n\geq 0} dx_1\ldots dx_n  \\
&= \int 1_{-t\leq 0} \left(\int_{\max(0,x_i-t)}^\infty e^{-x_1}dx_1 \right)^{n-1} e^{-x_i} dx_i\\
&=  1_{t\geq 0}\left[\int_0^t e^{-x_i}dx_i +  \int_t^\infty e^{-(x_i-t)(n-1) }e^{-x_i}dx_i\right]\\
&= 1_{t\geq 0}\left[1-e^{-t}\left(1-\frac 1n \right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

This yields the cdf of $X_i-X_{(1)}$ (which is independent of $i$ as expected). The distribution is neither discrete nor continuous.